# SQL Server database won't shrink

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, shrink, dbcc

I have a 31 GB database I got from a customer for a project. I'm coding and keeping the database in a 80GB Win7 VM. I got the db file and imported the database from that, and found that the space was being eaten up mostly by one table, with 240,000 images. I dropped most of those rows and now have 29,000MB available. I can't perform lots of functions because the drive is down to it's last few GB, and there are still a lot of records to modify (I'm changing a data type in several tables, but keep getting a active_transaction error). It's not shrinking via `DBCC_SHRINKDATABASE(0)` or `Tasks > Shrink > Database` or Files. It only shrinks to the size of the database when I first got it, it seems. How do I get it to release that space? If I can', can I export what data is still there to a smaller database, and then restore from that?

Running SQL Server 2012 and Management Studio.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: What recovery model are you using?

Comment: I am not certain. I'm currently expanding the hard disk of the VM so I can hopefully get around these issues. I'll let you know when it's done.

Comment: Run this query 'SELECT name, recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases' to find your recovery model.  If the recovery model is FULL, you will need to do a log file backup before shrink operations will be effective.

Comment: Full. How do I do this log file backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `dbcc shrinkdatabase` below the initial size setting.  If the initial size of your database is set to 50GB -- the MDF will always be at least 50GB, even if 29GB is free/available.

If you do in fact have free space, you can lower the initial size setting to a more reasonable value - but if the MDF will simply auto-grow again, this is not advised, as it incurs a high overhead.

To do this you would use `dbcc shrinkfile`.

Please see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56883/shrink-the-database-only-up-to-its-initial-size-which-is-set-after-creating-data) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This page describes how to make SQL server backups. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865(v=sql.110).aspx

If you haven't done so already, you will need to take a full backup before you can do a transaction log backup.